# Improve login experience by using google-api-java-client + OAuth 2.0 (Installed Application)

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, gdata, gdata-api, google-data

Previously, my installed application (desktop application) is using **gdata-java-client** with `ClientLogin` mechanism, for user to access Google service.

In order to provide seamless experience, the desktop application will store users previous entered username and password in encryption format. Whenever they wish to access Google service, the desktop application will automatically help users to fill in username + password information. (Even after application restarting) Users just need to single button click to access Google service.

[image]

The login code is as follow : http://jstock.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/jstock/jstock/file/808b03e824bf/src/org/yccheok/jstock/gui/Utils.java#l1520

I plan to migrate code to **google-api-java-client**, and use **OAuth 2.0**. Since my desktop application has no control over users entered username and password, users will be prompted with the following Windows every time they wish to use Google service.

[image]

The user flow doesn't seem seamless any-more, as users need to deal with the browser window, every-time after application restarting. **Is there any way for my desktop application, to remember their login information, so that they need not to respond to browser window every-time the application restarting?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question.  Yes, we are working on this right now.  The feature request is [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/issues/detail?id=27), and the changeset under review is [here](http://codereview.appspot.com/6242068/).  Our plan is to make it be available in the next version 1.11.0-beta some time in July.  For now, feel free to patch in FileCredentialStore from the changeset into your application and try it out.  More documentation about the OAuth 2.0 support in the Java client library can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Authorization_Code_Flow) (which will be updated for 1.11.0-beta with information about FileCredentialStore).

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward for official release very soon.

Comment: just to check with you. I go through the changeset. Basically, user still need to deal with browser window for the first time authentication process, right? is it possible for us to make it further "seamless", that user need not to deal with a browser at all? thanks.

Comment: also, referring to http://codereview.appspot.com/6242068/patch/24002/25020, I guess we are storing accessToken and refreshToken in a JSON file? how secure for us to do so? possible for a hacker gains access to that file, and does some nasty thing by using stored tokens? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp. This a general guide for your type of application - installed on client machine.

The tell you `These applications, in general, cannot keep secrets.` But if you already store users' credentials - will it really change something for you?